# How to blacklist KDE terminal in guake?

Tags: debian, terminal-emulator, konsole, guake

I am running guake on Debian testing -

```
 $guake --version
Guake Terminal: 3.8.1
VTE: 0.66.2
VTE runtime: 0.66.2
Gtk: 3.24.30
```

Fortunately or unfortunately KDE terminal seems to come in my guake sessions and I dunno why :(

[image]

FWIW, I also looked at the guake.desktop file entry -

```
/usr/share/applications$ cat guake.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Guake Terminal
Comment=Use the command line in a Quake-like terminal
TryExec=guake
Exec=guake
Icon=guake
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

And as can be seen, it doesn't show anything untoward. Please don't misunderstand me. I do like KDE terminal/konsole but not in guake. Is there any way to blacklist konsole/kde just from guake ???

Looking forward to knowing.

FWIW, I tried three sessions and it seems random. For e.g. in the first session, it was KDE, reboot and in DE and it was guake, the third session it was again KDE terminal. All the sessions were under mate 1.26

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @cas, the content on the terminal is not important in the above case. In the example shared above, I was just upgrading some packages. The core issue is the presence of KDE terminal in guake which IMHO should not happen. Why it is happening is beyond me.

Comment: If it's not important, then it shouldn't be there.   If it is important, post it as text, not as an image with unreadably tiny fonts.   You want people to help you, so it's in your best interest to not put obstacles in their way.

Comment: It's important just to illustrate how it looks. I am sure you are aware of how guake looks and the difference between guake and KDE term. It is not just in the looks but also functionality as well as shortcuts etc. I do not know any other way in which I could have shown the terminal emulator other than as I showed above. Guake is a top-down terminal emulator while KDE term is supposed to be not :(

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of this or not, but different people have different monitors with different resolutions and physical sizes and therefore pixels per inch, and different GPUs and different font settings and, most important of  all, different eyes. What might look perfectly legible to you on your monitor with your eyes after you've spent however long getting used to it will, to someone else, look like a mess that vaguely resembles some undifferentiated text in some kind of terminal. In short, your image of text adds nothing that your description of the problem didn't already say.

Comment: In any case, what is so hard to understand about "if you're asking for help, don't expect people to jump through unnecessary hoops to help you"?   Most people will just think "too much trouble, I couldn't be bothered" and move on to something else less annoying or more interesting.